# Use the same array in ejs and js

Tags: javascript, arrays, ejs

use the EJS array in JS file

in EJS

```
<% for (var i = 0; i<array.length;i++){ %>
        <li><%= array[i] %></li>
        
    <%}%>
```

then I want to use this array[i] in another js file such that in JS file:

```
function change() {
 this.innerHTML = array[0];
}
```

array should be the same

Answer (score 0):

Basically you echo it as JSON.

**file.ejs:**

```
<h1>hello</h1>
<script>
  var array = <%- JSON.stringify(array) %>
  console.log (array)
</script>
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: This is how you "pass" variable from server to client. What does  `console.log(array)` show for you?

Comment: it didn't show anything